# Multiple T-Test with Trended Data in R

Tags: r, t-test

I am having issue getting the p-values from a T-Test for a 'typical trended study'. The aggregated values for satisfaction by months are the following.

```
     [,1]      [,2]       [,3]    [,4]
[1,] "January" "February" "March" "April"
[2,] "8"       "4"        "10"    "7"
```

What I am trying to do is to compare the satisfaction from one month to another but more specifically to compare each month VS the previous month.

I need to compare:

- February vs January
- March vs February
- April vs March

I can get the p-value by sub setting my DF to keep only 2 months and to run a t.test.

```
DF2 <- filter(DF, Month == 'January' | Month == 'February')
fit <- t.test(DF2$Satisfaction ~ DF2$Month)
```

But I am pretty sure there's is more efficient way to get those numbers.

How could that be done?

Comment: How about a regression model with the use of contrast statements?

Comment: What's a 'typical trended study'? Do you just mean a linear regression of $y_t$ vs $t$? That seems problematic.

Comment: Just trying to see if there is a difference between the satisfaction score of a month and the previous one using a t-test.